# Recursively examine JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

I've got a number of JSON files of different structures that all have a number of levels of "nesting".  I need to examine certain keys that can appear anywhere in the object and update these.

Am struggling to handle the "nested" elements

I've got some code that have cobbled together from much Googling (am new to Python) and have tried both
instance(value,dict) and
type(value) is dict

However in no cases has the log showed "iterating deeper".

```py
def iterate(dictionary):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print('key {} -> value {}'.format(key, value))
        #if logic to update specific values
            print('Dict new value {}'.format(value))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
        #if type(value) is dict:
            print('Iterating deeper. Key {}'.format(key))
            dictionary[key] = iterate(value)
    return(dictionary)
```

Simple JSON example:

```
myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
 }
```

I'd expect to see "Iterating deeper. Key cars" printed out

Comment: `elif` without `if`?

Comment: yes- sorry- maybe not clear there- have removed the "if" logic for the specific use case (is commented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update:

```
def iterjson(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if (update_condition):
            data[key] = new_value

        print('key {} -> value {}'.format(key, value))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print('Iterating deeper. Key {}'.format(key))
            yield from iterjson(value)
        else:
            yield value
```

To iterate without updating:

```
def iterjson(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        print('key {} -> value {}'.format(key, value))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print('Iterating deeper. Key {}'.format(key))
            yield from iterjson(value)
        else:
            yield value
```

If you want to iterate with `list` as well:

```
def iterjson(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        print('key {} -> value {}'.format(key, value))
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print('Iterating deeper. Key {}'.format(key))
            yield from iterjson(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for i in value:
                yield i
        else:
            yield value
```